# TypeScript - Validate items in array map

Tags: arrays, typescript, validation

I have an interface for a book with an optional id (for case a new book which isn't saved yet to server):

```
interface Book {
   id?: string
}
```

When I fetch all books from backend - I use to create an object byId:

```
allIds: payload.map(book => book.id!),
```

where `allIds` declaration is:

```
allIds: string[]
```

as you can see, I added the `!` after the `book.id` in order to specify each book has an Id.
as if I won't do that, Typescript will not compile with:

> TS2322: Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Now, It's working with the `!`, and I don't expect any book to missing its id, but I would like to find an elegant way to validate it.. just in case.

I can do something like:

```
allIds: payload.map(book => {
   if (!book.id) {
      throw new Error("invalid book id")
   }
   return book.id
}),
```

but I would like to know if you have any idea for a nicer one-liner elegant solution to validate the items while mapping it.

Comment: So what should happen when `id` doesn't exist in the `Book` element?

Comment: raising Error is good enough for me for now @Buszmen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't expect any book to missing its id

Then remove `?` from the interface.

If you want to filter out elements without the `id` so `allIds` will be all strings and if you insist on one-liner:

```
const allStrings: string[] = payload.map(book => book.id).filter(<T>(v: T): v is Exclude<T, undefined> => typeof v !== 'undefined');
```

If for some reason you don't have access to `Book` interface, you can use this type for incoming data:

```
Required<Book>
```

which will make `id` no longer optional.

Comment: I can't remove the `?` as the same model is used to create new book.. and in this case the `id` is undefined (yet.. until it will be sent to server)

Answer (score 2):

How about encapsulating the assertion logic in a separate function?

```
function assertDefined<T>(t: T | undefined | null): T {
    if (t == undefined) throw new Error("undefined or null item.")
    return t
}

const res = payload.map(book => assertDefined(book.id)) // string[]
```

You could define a `propOrThrow` function to make it a bit shorter:

```
function propOrThrow<T, U>(mapper: (t: T) => U | undefined) {
    return (t: T): U => assertDefined(mapper(t))
}

const res2 = payload.map(propOrThrow(b => b.id)) // string[]
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GtkG8BQyRywAJgPwBcyAzmFKAOb4C+++pECANnFCgnQg6yAA5wAnt3RxS1DNgDaAXXYwAriARhgQ5HBo1oYACIQYoCKQA8AFQB8ACjDVbyAD7JNnCyCsfkEHVubgBKVzxCYmAYZGdkAF4ErxAfS1JQ5DAACyh0AHdAiEKAUSg8qEcAIlAANzhuMmQAI0wcMirQqKJ+MHUoECzWNU1tXUHRPNEAeShbXIK7ABpkAFUnAFs4UVFoamdXTIT7NYDvc3TMgmJkXv7Bg+RbcNPj-UNjM18rRy2d6GcoS6bHwgmEYFuEBoiTEkmksgAdH9HK1sIkTgYjFBTBc-KQUW0EWQgcgAPSk2j0JgqUFCET8GgAJhh4ikMlISO2jkm6BmcwW+RR6JaRIymXJlIYIEYKiAA)

Comment: Thank you! Both comments are great. I wish I could've approved both, but I was looking for one liner in the question.

Comment: Pick what you need :-). Be aware though, that a filter operation is different from a `throw` like in your question. Depends on, what you understand by validation

Comment: agree :) After thought about that we decided to go with filter to ignore such cases instead of breaking the app until the database will be investigated.